# Does it make sense for left-shifting negative integers by zero to be Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++

The standard advises (by way of omission) that the value of the left shift operand is inconsequential if the number shifted is negative, even though a shift by zero seems it should be well-defined.  Why is it considered Undefined Behavior (UB)?

```
    int a( -1     ); //ok
    int b( -1 << 0); //UB
```

Comment: *The standard advises* Please add the relevant details from the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should first ask a question: what is exactly is UB and why?

It is less trivial than it sounds.

For example. Let `x` be `min integer`. Then reducing it further is considered UB even though we know what the answer should be. E.g., reducing it by 1 changes it to `max integer`.

But why? Because compiler/optimizer assumes that reducing an integer makes it smaller and it can optimize the code based on this assumption. Which might cause various bizarre errors in the code if an `int` is reduced below `min integer`.

So why left shifting a negative integer is a UB? Even if the left shift is 0?

Imagine you have a code `y = x << c` where `c` is unsigned. The compiler can assume here that `x` is not negative as otherwise it would be a UB. So if there is some compliacted logical dependance that is optimized based on the assumption that `x` is non-negative and you pass negative `x` with `c = 0` it will cause the code to behave unexpectedly in random places despite the fact that the computation `y = x << c` makes perfect sense and will compute properly.

(Disclaimer, I haven't checked out anything specific regarding UB for `<<` operator, just gave a general answer regarding UB in C++)

You can checkout more information regarding UB on the internet. There are a couple of videos on it in CppCon on YouTube.

Edit: on bizarre behaviors that are created due to UB. Following program

```
if(x > x + 1)
{
    std::cout << " x is bigger than x+1 " << x << " " << x+1;
}
else
{
    std::cout << " x is smaller than x+1 " << x << " " << x+1;
}
```

with `x = 2147483647` (the `max integer`) will print

```
x is bigger than x+1 2147483647 -2147483648
```

if no optimization is applied (debug mode), but with -O2 enabled (release mode), it will most likely print

```
x is smaller than x+1 2147483647 -2147483648
```